# Setting up angularjs app for crawling

Tags: angularjs, google-search

I have an angular app set up to work in html5 mode with a #! fallback, so on most browsers it works with `http://example.com/foo/bar` and on less cool browsers we get `http://example.com/#!/foo/bar`. All that seems to work.

I have been going through trying to get google to crawl the site nicely, and it doesn't seem to be working as expected. I have set up `<meta property="fragment" content="!" />` in the page to signify to google to recrawl with `?_escaped_fragment_=`, and set up nginx to redirect to a static version of the page when it receives a request like this.

It *is* working for the front page - looking in the access logs I can see `http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment=` and can google "A sentence from the front page" and get the home page back as a result.

However it is *not* working for any of the interior pages, if I look in the access logs I can see a whole bunch of `http://example.com/foo/bar/?_escaped_fragment_=` rather than `http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/foo/bar/` as I might have expected.

Is there anything obvious I am missing to make google do what I want it to?

Answer (score 0):

I think that  is for AngularJS apps with HTML5 routes, and indeed, you should see requests with just ?_escaped_fragment_=, not ?_escaped_fragment_=/foo/bar/. For more info check section "3. Handle pages without hash fragments" here,  https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started.